# (Oracle) Is there a way to specify a jdbc-template parameter to use national characterset?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

I need to transfer a row from one Oracle database to another Oracle database using java program.
The problem is, those two DB has different NLS_CHARACTERSET (KO16MSWIN949, AL32UTF8) so when I transfer very long NVARCHAR data I face "ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column" error.

I am using jdbc template parameter for executing sql, and my query looks like this:
INSERT INTO TO_TABLE (NOTE1, NOTE2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)

When I tried to manually insert data, I noticed that if I put N in front of string then it solves problem, but I don't know how to do like this in jdbc parameter. Is there any way to do this? I cannot change characterset of both DB.

Comment: Not answering the question but just commenting. `LONG` is mostly obsolete nowadays. I would migrate towards a `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`. Also, it's a lot easier to use `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` as encoding. Disk space is no longer an issue as it used to be.